# DataBinding a DateTimePicker raises "DataBinding cannot find a row in the list that is suitable for all bindings."

Tags: data-binding, datetimepicker

I have a simple test application which reproduces an error I encountered recently. Basically I have a simple WinForm with databound TextBox and DateTimePicker controls, and a button. When I execute the code below *(on the button click)*, I get the error "DataBinding cannot find a row in the list that is suitable for all bindings". If I move the DataSource assignment into the form's constructor, I don't get the error.

If I remove the data binding for the DateTimePicker, it works fine.

Can anyone explain what the problem is ?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   private BindingSource bs;

   public Form1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();

      button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);

      bs = new BindingSource();
      bs.DataSource = typeof(Thing);

      this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "MyString");
      this.dateTimePicker1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Value", bs, "MyDate"));

      //Thing thing = new Thing { MyString = "Hello", MyNumber = 123, MyDate = DateTime.Parse("01-Jan-1970") };
      //bs.DataSource = thing;
      }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         Thing thing = new Thing { MyString = "Hello", MyNumber = 123, MyDate = DateTime.Parse("01-Jan-1970") };
         bs.DataSource = thing;
      }
   }

   public partial class Thing
   {
      public String MyString { get; set; }
      public Int32 MyNumber { get; set; }
      public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Thanks

**Edit:**

It seems that if I change the data binding for the DateTimePicker control such that I bind to the "Text" property, the problem goes away. I don't understand why that would be though, because "Value" is valid for data binding.

Comment: You should add your _edit_ as answer and accepted it if it solved your problem.

Comment: But it didn't solve the problem. It was a 'work-around' which happened to have the desired result, but didn't explain what the problem was - or how to solve it (as opposed to "avoid it").

Comment: You should add it as answer anyway if it is a workaround. Then people will see immediately that there is an approach which might be helpful in their situation (and you earn upvotes ;)).

Comment: To diagnose this issue, you will probably find success if you create the binding with `formattingEnabled` set to `true`, then subscribe its `BindingComplete` event. The `BindingCompleteEventArgs.ErrorText` will give you a much more helpful description of the error.

Comment: It solved my problem; DatePicker with "Value" raises "databinding cannot find a row that is suitable for all bindings", with "Text" no error, binding functions. It is a bug. Add as an answer; I could find this solution earlier, probably.

Answer (score 0):

*System.InvalidOperationException: 'DataBinding cannot find a row in the list that is suitable for all bindings.'*

This issue was solved by setting the `formattingEnabled` to `true` as below:

```cs
// private readonly BindingSource _bdsMembers = new() { DataSource = typeof(Member) };

this.dtpBirthday.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Value", _bdsMembers, "Birthday", true));
```