# Binding TimeSpan to DateTime control (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datetime, timespan

I am working with C# Winform and Entity Framework,

My question is, Is there a way to bind a TimeSpan property to DateTime control?

I have a `DataGridView` which is `DataBounded` to a entity framework `DbSet`. `DbSet` has a `TimeSpan` property which I binded to a `DateTime` control but displayed as `Time` only. my Binding is modeled here: [Entity Framework - (master detail) how to update Details which on a separate form from Master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547702/entity-framework-master-detail-how-to-update-details-which-on-a-separate-for)

Upon execution of the program, no error displayed on build but time is not displayed on the control as well as saving, time is not saved too. :(

Comment: Not quite sure what do you mean by "binded to DateTime control" - AFAIK there is no `DateTime` column type in `DataGridView`.

Comment: Yes, its outside of the `DataGridView`, along with other `TextBox`. If the user selects a row on the `DataGridView`, the values on the `TextBox` also changes based on the row selected, but Time didn't displayed/changed.

Comment: I see. So it's `DateTimePicker` control? What property of the control did you bind - `Value`?

Comment: Yes it is, I am binding it to a TimeSpan property on a DbSet on entity framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TimeSpan and DateTime are not interchangeable. I believe the simplest solution is create a control derived from `DateTimePicker` that exposes a `TimeSpan` property and bind to that.

```
public class TimePicker : DateTimePicker, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public TimePicker()
        : base()
    {
        this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
    }

    public TimeSpan Time
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Value.TimeOfDay;
        }
        set
        {
            this.Value = DateTime.Today.Add(value);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
    {
        base.OnValueChanged(eventargs);
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("Time"));
    }
}
```

Then you can bind to it something like this:

```
timePicker1.DataBindings.Add("Time", bindingSource1, "TS", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Comment: Hi @TnTinMn, Thank you for the answer, I tried your solution with the following: 1. Created a new class "TimePicker.cs". 2. On my form.designer.cs, changed this `this.TimeTxt = new System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker();` to this `this.TimeTxt = new M3dStation2.Controls.TimePicker();` 3. Changed my bindings to this `this.TimeTxt.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Time", this.enrollmedsBindingSource, "Time", false, dataSourceUpdateMode:onPropertyChanged));` but `onPropertyChanged` method is not on the list. Can you guide me on how to properly use your solution? thanks very much:)

Comment: Hi @TnTinMn, please disregard my previous reply, its just that `DataSourceUpdateMode` is under `System.Windows.Forms` namespace and its not included on the designer by default. The application can now build however upon opening the form `InvalidOperationException` occurs with this message: `Additional information: DataBinding cannot find a row in the list that is suitable for all bindings.`. Thank you in advance for the help :)

Comment: @Henry, I never seen that one before and will need to investigate. Is this error happening in the designer or when running or both?

Comment: Hi TnTinMn, The error occurs upon running, then upon opening of form, on this line of code `this.enrollmedsBindingSource.DataSource = context.enrollmeds.Local;`. Tried to open a record with valid time value, with no record yet, and with record but has null value on time on the database but all of them has the same exception :(

Comment: @Henry, This is a strange error.  I found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10908342/2592875) that claims setting the binding parameter `formattingEnabled` to true  is the solution (I showed using false).  [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859973/2592875), in the comment from  Simon MᶜKenzie,  offers some guidance on retrieving more diagnostic info that also involves `formattingEnabled=true`.  If those do not help, perhaps post a new question on that error.  I do not work with EF, but I did test the control with both a DataTable and BindingList as datasources with no problem.

Comment: Nice TnTinMn, you got it on the first linked you provided, setting the `formattingEnabled = true` removed the error as well as the binding, I can now view and edit the time on the field.. Thank You Very Much TnTinMn, your a life saver bro.. thanks again :) :) :). ps: can you edit the answer and set the `formattingEnabled` to `true`, so that other viewer can see the correct solution :) :) thanks again :) :)

Answer (score 1):

As I undesrand, you have `DateTimePicker` control with `Format` set to `DateTimePickerFormat.Time` and you are binding a `TimeSpan` to the [`Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

However, the `Value` property type is `DateTime`, so the binding silently is failing.

To fix the issue, bind to [`Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt6y6733(v=vs.110).aspx) property instead.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for your answer, however can you give me sample on how to bind DateTimePicker.Text to timespan? 
upon checking on my form designer i found code below:
`this.TimeTxt.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.enrollmedsBindingSource1, "Time", true));` but i dont know how to update it to  use the text instead of value., I am binding via designer.
thanks very much :)

Comment: If you are binding with code, you should have currently something like `dateTimePicker.DataBindingings.Add("Value", dataSource, "SomeProperty", true)`, so just change "Value" to "Text". If you are using designer, select the control, go to Properties -> Data Bindings, cut what is in Value and paste it into Text.

Comment: Hi Ivan, upon checking binding is already on the Text.

Is custom format has role on my problem?
`this.TimeTxt.CustomFormat = "hh:mm tt";`

`this.TimeTxt.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;`

Comment: Could be, although if I set it this way, the control displays the selected row time field, but cannot edit it. While when I bind to Value it does not even display it, which is more like what you described in the post.

Comment: Nope Ivan, both Text and Value didn't load or saved. Tried to set bind to both Text and Value but once I enter and Update field I get stucked (focus) on that field only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123119/discussion-between-henry-and-ivan-stoev).

Comment: Take a look at https://dotnetfiddle.net/qXEcC2 Create a new Windows Forms project and copy/paste the whole content of the fiddle in the Program.cs (replace everything inside). Then run it and let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi Ivan, Thank you for the reply, I tried both .NETfiddle you sent on a new project. 
Yes it displayed the time properly, and I already tested it on my project.
However this is only 1 way binding. 
If i try to change the time on DateTimePicker, I got stucked on the DateTimePicker control.
Even clicking close on the application is not allowed unless i changed the selection on DataGridView which reverts my changes.
you can see the screen here for proof [link](http://imgur.com/a/ieLup)  :)

Comment: I see, thank you:) The difference with my tests is AM/PM designator - I don't have such (using 24 hour clock) and couldn't let it show it, even setting en-US culture at the beginning. Anyway, I think you should consider [TriTinMn](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2592875/tntinmn) answer, sounds quite reasonable and works in my environment.

Comment: Hi Ivan, Thank you for the help, I will try his solution instead bro.. thank you very much again :) :) :)

Comment: You are welcome bro :) I've upvoted and tested his solution and it worked for me, so hope you'll have no problems applying it to your code.